# SQL Update does not work. Why?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

Just a simple SQL question - Bbut i can't figure out whats wrong

```
"UPDATE veranstaltungen
    SET name = '$nameV', SET Datum = '$DatumV', SET beschreibung = '$beschreibungV'
 WHERE id = '$id'"
```

I want to update the table row where the id is $id. But nothing happens here?
the variables are all correct

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL). And please use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give it like

```
 "UPDATE veranstaltungen  SET name = '$nameV', Datum = '$DatumV', beschreibung = '$beschreibungV' WHERE id = '$id'"
```

Answer (score 2):

> but i can't figure out whats wrong

Mysql has a wonderful feature, personally for you. It is called `mysql_error()`
run this function and echo it's output to see what your server will tell about this query.
I believe that you can trust to your server much more than someone who passed along this question.